# How to query emails used by more than one user by using LEFT JOIN instead of GROUP BY?

Tags: mysql

Lets say I have a table called user_table:

```
user_table
 id
 first_name
 last_name
 gender
 email
 created_at
```

How would I write a query listing emails used by more than one user?

EDIT:

Can the same results be achieved by use LEFT JOIN instead of GROUP BY?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT email
FROM user_table
GROUP BY email
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

---

Alternatively, you can use an INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u1.email 
FROM user_table u1
INNER JOIN user_table u2
  ON u1.email = u2.email AND u1.id < u2.id
```

Comment: Can you perform the same task, but instead of using GROUP BY, use LEFT JOIN